# Customizing the tooltip with chartkick in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, google-visualization, chartkick

I'm doing a rails app and was able to get [chartkick](http://chartkick.com/) working but customizing it is a bit of a pain in the butt. I'm trying to customize the tooltip with the Google chart API but I can't seem to figure out. I just want to be able to change the text, **"Value"**.

Could someone put me in the right direction.

Here is my code:

```
<%=
  column_chart [
    ["Strongly Disagree", p[1]],
    ["Disagree", p[2]],
    ["Neutral", p[3]],
    ["Agree", p[4]],
    ["Strongly Agree", p[5]]
  ],
  height: "220px",
  library: {
    width: 665,
    fontName: "Helvetica Neue",
    colors: ["#29abe2"],
    tooltip: {
      textStyle: {
        color: "#333333"
      }
    },
    bar: {
      groupWidth: "50%"
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: "Everyone",
      titleTextStyle: {
        italic: false,
        color: '#777'
      },
      gridlines: {
        color: "#eeeeee"
      },
      viewWindow: {
        max: m
      }
    }
  }
%>
```

Comment: Hey @Jan did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The chartkick documentation is sparse, but if this system works the way I suspect it does, then you need to add an array of column headers to the start of your data, eg:

```
[
    ["Label for column 0", "Label for column 1"],
    ["Strongly Disagree", p[1]],
    ["Disagree", p[2]],
    ["Neutral", p[3]],
    ["Agree", p[4]],
    ["Strongly Agree", p[5]]
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that just adds another label.

Comment: What does it look like?

Comment: It doesn't work the way I expected it to then.  Given that this is a new product with a small user base, you might have better luck contacting the [author](https://github.com/ankane) for help.